# Dynamically name a JSON property

Tags: javascript, json

I've been trying to create a dynamically named JSON property but I keep hitting on errors. Honestly I  don't know if this is possible to achieve with Javascript. Anyway here is my problem.

Let's suppose I'm creating a JSON object like the following code:

```
var DTO = { 'NewObject' : GetFormData() };  
var DTO = { 'UpdateObject' : GetFormData() };  
var DTO = { 'DelObject' : GetFormData() };
```

Now what I've been trying to do is to dynamically name the JSON property because with something like `'New' + ClassName` (`ClassName` being a var with a string value) but it gives me a syntax error. Is there a way to do this to become something like:

```
var DTO = { 'New' + ClassName : GetFormData() };  
var DTO = { 'Update' + ClassName : GetFormData() };  
var DTO = { 'Delete' + ClassName : GetFormData() };
```

I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Would this suit your needs ?

```
var DTO = {}; DTO['New' + ClassName] = GetFormData();
```

Answer (score 22):

With ECMAScript 6, you can use computed property names in object property definitions.

For example, you can simply write:

```
var DTO = { ['New' + ClassName] : GetFormData() };
```

More information: http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames

Answer (score 12):

This is just "an object". JSON is a serialization to a string, not an object type.

If you want to use a variable as a property name, then you must create an object first, then assign the data using [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).

```
var foo = {};
var bar = 'baz';
foo[bar] = '123';
alert(foo.baz);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var DTO = Object();
DTO['New' + ClassName] = GetFormData();
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs to keep previous data too, then use the below code:

```
var DTO = {}; 
DTO = {...DTO,['New' + ClassName] = GetFormData()}
DTO = {...DTO,['Update' + ClassName] = GetFormData()}
```

Final DTO will store both the New & Update fields.