# Javascript equivalent of php's $object->{$stringvar} = 1 without eval()?

Tags: php, javascript

How do i create properties of an object from values of other variables without using the eval() function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically name a JSON property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318532/dynamically-name-a-json-property)

Comment: I wouldn't agree that this is a duplicate; wildly different roots for this question, though they're ultimately the same solution. Leaving this Question means a bunch of people find it who might not find the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With array notation:

```
obj[stringvar] = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var object = {}, stringvar = "name";
object[stringvar] = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use other variables as property names like this:

```
var a = 'property';
var b = {};

b[a] = 'hello';
```

This can also then be accessed in he following way:

```
b.property;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this with object literal notation:

```
var method = 'foo()';
// call it
myobject[method];
```

So you would do:

```
object[stringvar] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the bracket notation:

```
var o = { key: 'value' };
var member = 'key';

o[member] = 'oherValue';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myobject = {};
var stringvar = "test";
myobject[stringvar] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects allow for on-demand properties creation. Just set the property you want:

```
var object = {name:'A', id:1};
object.description = "Test";
alert(object.description);
```