# On checkbox click storing value into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an checkbox list like following:

```
$('.check-user').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var user_id = $this.attr('value');
    var brandContainer = $this.closest('.pop-state').siblings('.pop-brands');
    brandContainer.html('<p style="margin: 10px !important;">Processing... </p>');
    $.post('/user/usersBrands', { userId: user_id } , function(data) {

        var brands = JSON.parse(data);
        var container = $('<div class="pop-mission-co" />');

        brands.forEach(function (brand, index) {
            var isRegisteredToBrand = null;
            if(brand.userId==null)
            {
                isRegisteredToBrand = false;
             }
            else{
                isRegisteredToBrand = true;
            }
            container.append(buildBrand(brand.id, brand.name, isRegisteredToBrand, index));
        });
        function buildBrand(id, name, isActive, index) {
            var isChecked = isActive ? 'checked="checked"' : ' ';
            return $(
                '<div class="pop-mission-to">' +
                    '<label>' +
                        '<input class="check-brand"' +
                            isChecked +
                            'type="checkbox"' +
                            'name=""' +
                            'value="' + id + '"' +
                            'data-id="' + index + '">'
                                + name +
                    '</label>' +
                '</div>'
            );
        }
        brandContainer
            .children('p').remove();
        brandContainer
            .html(container)
            .find('.pop-mission-co').show();
    });
    brandContainer.on('change', '.check-brand', function() {

        console.log($(this).attr("checked"));

    });
});
```

The  checkbox list is created after a $.post in jQuery and now I need to handle the event when each of these checkboxes is checked like following:

```
 brandContainer.on('change', '.check-brand', function() {

            console.clear();
    var checked = "";
    if($(this).attr("checked"))
    {
        checked = "checked";
    }
    else
    {
        checked = "unchecked";
    }
    console.log(checked);
    console.log($(this).val());

        });
```

As you can see I'm using a delegated event handler to check whether the checkbox has been checked or not... When a user clicks on 1 checkbox I should put it in the array like following:

```
Array { "checked", "1" }
```

When user clicks on another checkbox the array should be updated like this:

```
Array {  "checked", "1", "checked", "2" }
```

If the user unchecks the  checkbox that he already checked, lets say second one with value 2, the array should look like this:

Array {  "checked", "1", "unchecked", "2" }

The process goes on... Can someone help me out with this ? Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Guys I've updated my question and shown how I fetch the value of the current textbox and whether it is checked or not...

Comment: I think you want to create dynamically named property. check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318532/dynamically-name-a-json-property

Comment: Why dont you create an array like `Array { 1=> 'checked' , 2 => 'unchecked' }`

Comment: yea but how to do that dynamicalls... I have to expand the array each time new checkbox has been checked, and update the array if the unchecked item already exists in the array lol... Can you reply in a form of answer so I can see what you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work.

```
var checkbox_events = [];
brandContainer.on('change', '.check-brand', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked') {
        checkbox_events[$(this).val()] = 'checked';
    } else {
        checkbox_events[$(this).val()] = 'unchecked';
    }
});
```

Comment: It will be generate following output: ["checked", 1]

Comment: When the same  checkbox is unchecked I shouldn't add the new value into the array, but simply update the current one... Also every checkbox should be treated like an array for itself... Do you understand what I'm trying to say ? :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think what you want is an array that has the states of all checkboxes. If there is a state present, it is to be 'updated'. I think my updated answer should work if I understand you right.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted !!! :) How can I access the value if these ID's    now ? I'm guessing I'd usually do a for loop and do like this: checkbox_events[i]['somevalue'] or ??

Comment: Awesome. You can use `$(checkbox_events).each(function(index,value) {});`. `index` will have the checkbox key and `value` will have `checked/unchecked`.  Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: And when I pass it to the PHP function... Do I access it the same way ? :) I should be able to access both the value of the index and the value itself (1 and checked or unchecked) within the PHP function itself... :) Edit: I've accepted ur answer phreakv6 :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes you can post it as a `json` and in php do a `json_decode` and use a `foreach` to access your `checkbox_events` hash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114106/discussion-between-perkes456-and-phreakv6).